# How to configure pam.d config files in CentOS

Tags: centos, pam

I am hardening a CentOS 6.7 VM to CIS standards.

https://benchmarks.cisecurity.org/tools2/linux/CIS_CentOS_Linux_6_Benchmark_v1.1.0.pdf

The above is the document I am using to harden the image. I am working on 6.3.2 and 6.3.3 on page 133-135.

My question is this, how do I manage the password-auth and system-auth files so that they will comply with the CIS specifications?

So far I read about and implemented the following:

I copied the password-auth-ac and system-auth-ac files and named them -local.
I recreated symlinks between -local files and their standard counterparts.

One way I read to accomplish this was to only include the additional requirements in the -local files and insert statements to include the -ac files.

The problem I see with this is such: The CIS document calls for system-auth to have the following for pam_cracklib.so

```
password required pam_cracklib.so try_first_pass retry=3 minlen=14 dcredit=-1 ucredit=-1 ocredit=-1 lcredit=-1
```

by default, system-auth-ac generates with the following for the pam_cracklib.so

```
password requisite pam_cracklib.so try_first_pass retry=3 type=
```

so if I list the first string in my -local file and then have a line that says:

```
password include system-auth-ac
```

will the correct password requirements get met? The document also mentions "Ensure they appear after pam_env.so and before pam_deny.co:

If I use includes and list a password requirement will it logically fall in between those?

Any insight on this is appreciated,